# How to Capture Value of jQuery Mobile Flip Switch

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the following code segment but can not seem to capture the flipped value.

Java segment in the Head and HTML in Body:

```
<script>
$('#pauseslider').bind('change', function(event, data) {

 if ($(this).slider().val() == 'off') {
  alert($('No');

 if ($(this).slider().val() == 'on') {
  alert($('ON');

 });

 //**********************************
 </script>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a">
        <label for="pauseslider" data-theme="e">Mode</label> 
        <select name="pauseslider" id="pauseslider" data-role="slider" data-theme="e">
            <option value="off" data-theme="a">OFF</option>
            <option value="on" data-theme="a">ON</option>
         </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Wrap your code in `$(document).on("pageinit", function`.

Comment: What Omar said: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Wju8L/